# destroyWindow hangs - mfc, c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got a slideshow program written in C++ with MFC.  It's been working pretty well, with one window showing images on my secondary monitor.

I decided to add an option to display a smaller image (think "thumbnail") on my primary monitor.

When I stop the slideshow, the app makes a call to destroyWindow("Main Screen") which works fine, then the next call is destroywindow("Thumbnail") which hangs up.

While the app is running, I get a crosshair icon over the main screen, and an aero cursor over the thumbnail.  If I try to do anything with the thumbnail image - such as click in the image or click resize on the window, it takes a few seconds for the action to take effect.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.  I'm using openCV2.

Comment: Change order of calling DestroyWindow

Comment: While the program is hung, break into the debugger to see what it's doing.  That's what debuggers are for!  Debugging the DestroyWindow problem might shed some light on the other one.

Comment: There is no Windows API or MFC call `destroywindow` nor `destroyWindow`. If you are using a library, use the respective tags on your question. If your code fails, deduce a [mcve] and show that. If you are in fact calling [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx), make sure to heed the warning: *"A thread cannot use `DestroyWindow` to destroy a window created by a different thread."*

Comment: I thought I was posting this message in an opencv library forum.  So I'm not sure how I got it here!  Paul - I did try doing that to no avail.  If anyone happens on this message thread - the issue was that I was calling opencv functions from within a thread of my app, and all gui calls are supposed to be from the main process.  So I created some custom messages and posted a notification back to the primary thread for processing.  That fixed it.  Thanks for your help!